# In Clojure, how can I add support for common functions like empty? and count to my new type?

Tags: clojure

As I understand, Clojure makes it "easy" to solve the "expression problem".

But I can't find details how to do this. How can I create a new type (like defrecord) that handles things like empty? and count ?

Answer (score 5):

The two examples [empty?](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/empty_q) and [count](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/count) functions are part of Clojure's core and their implementations are driven by performance considerations, so they may not be the best examples for the solution of the [expression problem](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-clojure-protocols/). Anyway:

- You can make `empty?` work by making `seq` work on your type, for example by implementing the [Seqable](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Seqable.java) interface.
- You can make `count` work by implementing the [Counted](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Counted.java) interface.

Example code:

```
(deftype Tuple [a b]
  clojure.lang.Counted
  (count [_] 2)

  clojure.lang.Seqable
  (seq [_] (list a b)))

(count (->Tuple 1 2)) ;=> 2
(empty? (->Tuple 1 2)) ;=> false
```

A more general solution for a new function would be either:

- Creating a [multimethod](https://clojure.org/reference/multimethods) for your function. Now you need to write custom methods (via `defmethod`) for the supported types.
- Creating a [protocol](https://clojure.org/reference/protocols) that contains your function and making the types satisfy the protocol via `extend-protocol` or `extend-type`.

In either case you have the ability to create a default implementation and new implementations for new or existing types any time. Even during runtime!

Comment: Notably you cannot do this for `defrecord` types, which are supposed to be map-like, and come with built-in implementations of the various map interfaces which cannot be replaced. To build custom types with no built-in behavior you have to use `deftype`, as this answer does.